# Я.Расписания: обновление данных расписания в локальном файле без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Цель: сделать локальный html-документ расписаний Ж/Д для использования на мобильных устройствах. Документ будет включать собственные стили и 20 - 40 станций (для каждой станции модальное окно с таблицей расписания).

Вопрос: возможно ли реализовать обновление таблиц с расписаниями внутри локального документа (либо по одной, либо всех сразу), минимизируя объём трафика, для последующего пересохранения этого html-файла из окна браузера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно.
Читать файл с помощью `input[type='file']` и `File API` (особо хитрым можно так же заюзать хранилище браузера), а предлагать сохранить новые данные через ссылку.
Как-то так:

```js
class Viewer{
 constructor(){
        // Здесь данные хранятся
     this.data = null;
 }
 
    /**
     * Ищем элементы и ставим для них слушатели
     */
 init(){
    [this.loadBtn, this.saveBtn, this.view, this.empty, this.addRowBtn] = document.querySelectorAll('#load, #save, #addRow, #view, #empty');

    this.loadBtn.addEventListener('change', this.loadFile.bind(this));
  this.addRowBtn.addEventListener('click', this.addRow.bind(this));
  this.saveBtn.addEventListener('click', this.saveData.bind(this));
 }
 
    /**
     * Если файл выбран, пробуем читать и парсить из JSON
     * Формат файла: [{id: Number, value: String}...]
     *
     * @param {Event} e Объект события выбора файла
     */
 loadFile(e){
   let file = e.target.files[0];
   
   if(file === undefined) return;
   
   let fr = new FileReader();
   
   fr.onload = r => {
     try{
       this.data = JSON.parse(fr.result);
          
          if(!Array.isArray(this.data))
            this.data = [];
     }catch(e){
       throw new Error('The file is broken!');
     }

     this.insert();
   }
   fr.readAsText(file);
 }

    /**
     * Вставляем данные в таблицу
     */
 insert(){
   let result = '';
   
   this.data.forEach(e => {
     if(!e.id || !e.value)
       return;
     
     result += `<tr><td>${+e.id}</td><td>${e.value}</td></tr>`;
   });
      
      if(result === '')
        result = `<tr id='empty'><td rowspan='100%' align='center'>Пусто</td></tr>`;
   
   this.view.innerHTML = '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th></tr>' + result;
 }

    /**
     * Добавляем рандомные данные
     */
 addRow(){
      if(this.data === null) return;
      
   let [ids, wordsLen] = this.data.reduce((a, e) => a[0].push(e.id) && a[1].push(e.value.length) && a, [[], []]),
       id = 0,
       value = '',
       alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

      // Длина новой строки - от 1-го до средней длины строк (или 20, если длина большая)
      wordsLen = this.rand(1, Math.min(+wordsLen.reduce((a, e) => a += e, 0) / Math.round(wordsLen.length), 20));

      // Ищем уникальный ID
      // Если за 10 циклов на находим - плюём на уникальность и выходим
      let f = 0;
   do{
    id = this.rand();
    f++;

    if(f === 10)
     break;
   }while(ids.includes(id))

      // Из алфавита вырезаем случайную букву wordsLen раз
   for(let i = 0; i < wordsLen; i++){
    value += alphabet.substr(this.rand(0, alphabet.length - 2), 1);
   }

      // Обновляем массив данных
   this.data.push({
    id: id,
    value: value
   });
   
   this.view.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td><td>${value}</td></tr>`;
 }

 rand(min = 0, max = 999){return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;}

    /**
     * Сохранение данных
     *
     * @param {Event} e Объект события клика
     */
 saveData(e){
        if(this.data === null) return;
      
        // Красиво превращаем данные в строку
  let data = JSON.stringify(this.data, null, 2),
   link = document.createElement('A'),
   filename = 'Data.json';
      
     link.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
     link.setAttribute('download', filename);
     link.style.display = 'none';
     document.body.appendChild(link);

     link.click();

     link.remove();
 }
}

let viewer = new Viewer();
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', viewer.init.bind(viewer))
```

```html
<input type='file' id='load' value='Загрузить данные' /> | <input type='button' id='save' value='Сохранить данные' /><hr />
<table id='view'>
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  <tr id='empty'><td colspan='100%' align='center'>Пусто</td></tr>
</table>
<hr />
<input type='button' id='addRow' value='Добавить строку' />
```

Прямой доступ и неявное обращение на чтение/запись к ФС из JS никто не даст, поэтому ручками нужно выбирать и сохранять.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы желаете иметь постоянное изменение расписания в реальном времени, то обратите внимание на технологию Гугл **[GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification)](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/)**. Эта спецификация позволяет предприятиям общественного транспорта предоставлять разработчикам расписания движения с изменениями в режиме реального времени. В указанной документации приведены примеры для применения в Картах Гугл, но вы легко сможете адаптировать эту технику и для стандарта html.